# Jenkins returns status code -1 (hudson.plugins.git.GitException)

Tags: java, git, jenkins, windows-server-2008-r2

I am getting the below error in Jenkins while fetching tags from git repo.

Jenkins version: 1.657 Server: Windows Server 2012 R2

```
Unexpected error!
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://testbuilduser@bitbucket.org/wheeve/newco.git +refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/* --prune" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1719)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1463)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
 at net.uaznia.lukanus.hudson.plugins.gitparameter.GitParameterDefinition.generateContents(GitParameterDefinition.java:249)
 at net.uaznia.lukanus.hudson.plugins.gitparameter.GitParameterDefinition$DescriptorImpl.doFillValueItems(GitParameterDefinition.java:432)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:320)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:163)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:124)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:233)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:233)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:233)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
 at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
 at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
 at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
 at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
 at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
 at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
 at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
 at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried by restarting the service and also tried by killing all the JAVA processors and by restarting the service and still failed to retrieve tags from the repo. Please help me to sort this issue out.

Comment: What happens when you execute command from above on that machine manually?

Comment: @Ivan this is what am getting. `C:\Program Files\Git\bin>git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://buildbotwheeve@bitbucket.org/wheeve/newco.git +refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/* --prune
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: You should run it in a git directory. Instead you are running it in git bin directory. So please change location and run again. If still getting error please comment here.

Comment: For your info, this error comes because of askpass also. please search about it. It may help you after you unset the askpass. btw askpass is not a boolean value to be set. just check that also.

Comment: This is what I am getting now. `C:\Program Files\Git>git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://buildbotwheeve@bitbucket.org/wheeve/newco.git
'git.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @Daz, you need to run `git.exe` in a directory where you have your Git repository checked out or want to check it out. To do that you need to add path to `git.exe` to `PATH` variable on that Windows machine.